# Using Task.FromResult(0) from FSharp

Tags: f#

I am rewriting some legacy C# classes into F#.  One of the classes implements the IIdentityMessageService with the single method of  this.SendAsync(identityMessage)

In the C# code, I see this

```
    if (transportWeb != null)
        return transportWeb.DeliverAsync(message);
    else
        return Task.FromResult(0);
```

I tried it in F# like this

```
    if  transportWeb != null then
        transportWeb.DeliverAsync(message)
    else
        Task.FromResult(0)
```

and I am getting an error on the last line

```
This expression was expected to have type
    Task    
but here has type
    Task<'a>
```

What am I missing?  Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like `DeliverAsync` returns a `Task`, so you need both branches to return a `Task`. `Task.FromResult(0)` returns a `Task<int>` so you need to explictly upcast it to a `Task`:

```
else
    Task.FromResult(0) :> Task
```

Comment: Good call. Also, there is an error in my code for the null check.  The compiler caught it after I fixed the return value.  Thanks!